# PHPExcel export HTML table to xlsx

Tags: php, excel, export, phpexcel, xlsx

I need to **export HTML table** with data from database to **xlsx file** as easily as possible.

I've tried `PHPExcel` and some JS plugins, but **unsuccessfully**.

Is there any new solution?

Everything I found was almost 10 years old.

This is what I created:

My HTML form:

```
<form action="download.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Export" />
</form>
```

My PHPExcel code (file: download.php):

```
<?php

require_once "../Classes/PHPExcel.php";

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'hello world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Chesse1');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

When I click the button, it downloads the file, but I can't open it, because of **"wrong format"**.

I also tried this video tutorial:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dc3a4isHNE&t](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dc3a4isHNE&t=)

Exporting Excel file worked but another problem appeared.

The problem I had was **wrong charset**.
I need to use characters like: **ě,š,č,ř,ž,ý,á,í** etc. and these characters were totally messed up.

Comment: #1.... Make absolutely certain that there is absolutely no other output from your script, not even new lines, that is being sent to the browser

Comment: #2.... Use UTF-8 for all strings and texts, and then it won't mess up characters like ě,š,č,ř,ž,ý,á,í etc

Comment: Why would you expect "new" solutions for something designed to write files in native Excel formats that are 10+ years old?

Comment: #3.... Use the correct content type header with the format that you are writing; an xlsx file should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`; the older `application/vnd.ms-excel` is used only for `xls` files, which are created with the `Excel5` Writer

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for advices! **#1** I'll definitely check it! **#2** I'm sure that everything is encoded in UTF-8, but still czech characters don't display correctly. You are right about looking for new solution. **#3** I also tried header for xlsx format, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

```
<?php  
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');  
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'xlsexport');  
$setSql = "SELECT `ur_Id`,`ur_username`,`ur_password` FROM `tbl_user`";  
$setRec = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql);  
$columnHeader = '';  
$columnHeader = "Sr NO" . "\t" . "User Name" . "\t" . "Password" . "\t";  
$setData = '';  
while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {  
    $rowData = '';  
    foreach ($rec as $value) {  
        $value = '"' . $value['id'] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $value['ur_username'] . '"'."\t".'"' . $value['ur_password'] . '"';  
        $rowData .= $value;  
    }  
    $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
}  
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = User_Detail_Reoprt.xlsx");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");  
echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";  
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm completely new to PHP and this code is a bit confusing for me. **In which variable should I put my table content?** Anyway.. thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the format and added buffer clean in your code.

```
<?php

require_once "../Classes/PHPExcel.php";

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xls"');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A20')->setValue("TEST PHPEXCEL");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Chesse1');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Sometimes `Excel2007` gets conflict with `Excel5`. And it depends on the library file available in the PHPExcel. I had same problem of file not opening after download. So I changed to `Excel5`

Sample data has been inserted to check whether data arise in the excelsheet or not. You can replace it with the database variable.

Also `ob_end_clean()` helps to avoid the buffering of cache.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mb_internal_encoding')) {
    $oldEncoding=mb_internal_encoding();
    mb_internal_encoding('latin1');
}

require_once 'addons/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; //Update your Path for PHPExcel Class
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle("Template Title");

$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);

$sheet->SetCellValue('A1', 'hello world!');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

if (function_exists('mb_internal_encoding')){
    mb_internal_encoding($oldEncoding); 
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=helloworld.xlsx");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"'); //You need to remove double quotes from File Name

Comment: header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=helloworld.xlsx");

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please [edit] your answer and add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.